# How to calculate "real" bounds when the zoom level is low and the map spans several maps?

Tags: google-maps

How would you be able to get the "real" lat long bounds of a map when the zoom is low enough to actually contain "several earth" longitude wise?
I need to know the longitude extent of the current map view port but if I use the getbounds of the map I get an erroneous value due to the fact that the lat lng are modulo 360.

Edit: This is for the v3 maps. My need is I want to know when precisely the earth is repeated across my map pane, I need this information to be able to:
1) save and set the current bounds of the map (I can also do it with zoom and center that's true)
2) get a custom overlayview to take up the whole screen (to implement a glass panel on top of the map and intercept a number of events when in certain mode of my application). For this I have no other option (to my knowledge) than to implement the draw method and resize my own div element to fit the map boundaries in the current viewport.

Comment: Give us an example. What map parameters did you set, what method did you call to get the map bounds, and what result did you get back?  Oh, and is this the v2 or v3 API?

Comment: Yes sorry the initial question was rather vague, I edited and added some more information

Answer (score 0):

What are the bounds you get from the map? The correct bounds would be -180,-90 180,90 (the whole earth). Just because you see multiple earths on screen you are still dealing with a single spheroid, and therefore the bounds cannot exceed those limits.

I would have hoped that, when you see multiple earths on screen, adding a new market at 0,0 will show you that marker once for each instance of 0,0 (off Africa's coast)